# how to add a calculated column to a dataframe in scala/python?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, scala, azure-databricks

First of all, I'm new to programming and just a beginner playing on azure databricks.
Currently, I have a dataframe named 'df' (huge data set with 50+ columns and above million rows) and I would like to add another calculated column to it based on the existing 'timestamp' column in it.

I'm comfortable with SQL so I converted the DF into the table and tried using

```
ALTER TABLE logdata 
ADD sli VARCHAR(255)
```

but I was always hitting an error (code is right, working perfectly on W3schools) as below

> Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
>   no viable alternative at input 'ALTER LOGDATA'(line 1, pos 6)

So, I'm trying to use either scala or python. My use case is out of the huge dataframe 'df' I have a column called 'timestamp'(like 2019-04-18 07:31:45). I need to create a custom column that grabs only the 'mins' section of the timestamp and inserts it into the newly created column of the dataframe. I tried using withcolumn and lit from other user's suggestions, but no success. Can anyone help me with this please how to loop for this huge dataset?

Answer (score 0):

An example using Dataframe and the ***minute*** sql function:

```
object timeTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[1]").getOrCreate()

    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.minute

    val df = spark.createDataFrame(
      spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(
        Row(1, Timestamp.valueOf("2015-12-02 03:04:00")),
        Row(2, Timestamp.valueOf("1999-01-01 01:45:20"))
      )), StructType(
        List(StructField("id", IntegerType, true),
          StructField("time", TimestampType, true)))
    )

    df.withColumn("min", minute(col("time"))).show()
  } 
}
```

It gives:

```
+---+--------------------+---+
| id|                time|min|
+---+--------------------+---+
|  1|2015-12-02 03:04:...|  4|
|  2|1999-01-01 01:45:...| 45|
+---+--------------------+---+
```